# Set selected ComboBoxItem from Xml datasource (XmlDataProvider)

Tags: wpf, xpath, combobox

How do i display the currently selected item in the ComboBox? The information which item is selected is stored in an XML file.

How it looks on application start up:

[image: current situation]

How it should look on application start up:

[image: desired situation]

The XML Data source looks like this:

```
<Contact>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
</Contact>
```

This is what i tried (among lots of other variations)

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=Contact/Gender, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="cmbGender" Width="100" >
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />
</ComboBox>
```

I guess this is the way you would do it without XmlDataProvider. Is there a way to set the IsSelected with an XPath expression?

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbGender" Width="100" >
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" IsSelected="True"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />
</ComboBox>
```

**Edit:**
This is how i set the Datasource:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="DataProvider" XPath="/" />
    </Grid.DataContext>

     // Binding is working fine
    <TextBox Name="txtLastname" Width="100" Text="{Binding XPath=Contact/Lastname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    // not working
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=Contact/Gender, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="cmbGender" Width="100" >
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" />
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where do you set the DataContext to the XmlDataProvider?

Comment: see my edit. But i'm pretty sure it is NOT the datasource because it works fine for all other controls

Comment: have you tried this Binding XPath=Contact/Gender/text()?

Comment: not working, the ComboBox is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text Property is the key, this is how it works:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding XPath=Contact/Gender, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="cmbGender" Width="100">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" />
</ComboBox>
```